# PriorityQueue Sort By Map Value with out Lambda (older version of Java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, collections, comparator

Following problem require solution before jdk 1.8.
I have a string S="aab". All the character is put into `HashMap` based on their frequency. Now declaring a `PriorityQueue` with `Comparator`. So that all characters can be stored in the `PriorityQueue` in descending order base on the frequency. But I am getting the following error--

```java
    Map<Character, Integer> dicT = new HashMap<>();        
    for(int i = 0;i < S.length(); i++) {           
       dicT.put(S.charAt(i), dicT.getOrDefault(S.charAt(i), 0) + 1);
    }

    PriorityQueue<Character> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue(
        new Comparator<Map.Entry<Character,Integer>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry1, 
                               Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry2) {
                return entry2.getValue().compareTo(entry1.getValue());
            }
        });
        
    maxHeap.addAll(dicT.keySet());
```

Error(Using newer jdk to demonstrate problem only, the target jdk version is before jdk 1.8) ---

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Character
> cannot be cast to class java.util.Map$Entry
> (java.lang.Character and java.util.Map$Entry are in module
> java.base of loader 'bootstrap') at line 14,
> Solution$1.compare at line 659,
> java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpUsingComparator at line 636,
> java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp at line 329,
> java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.offer at line 310,
> java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.add at line 187,
> java.base/java.util.AbstractQueue.addAll at line 22,
> Solution.reorganizeString at line 54,
> **DriverSolution**.**helper** at line 84,
> **Driver**.main

But if I use lambda then it's working fine --

```java
PriorityQueue<Character> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue(
        (x, y) -> dicT.get(y) - dicT.get(x));
    maxHeap.addAll(dicT.keySet());
```

Please help me how can I write the block of code with out lambda?

Comment: Don’t omit the `<>` when creating an instance of a generic class, i.e. `new PriorityQueue<>(…)` and don’t ignore the compiler warnings you get because you omitted it. By the way, `dicT.put(S.charAt(i),dicT.getOrDefault(S.charAt(i),0)+1);` can be simplified to `dicT.merge(S.charAt(i), 1, Integer::sum);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring a `PriorityQueue<Character>` which uses a `Comparator<Character>` to define priority. But you are providing a `Comparator<Map.Entry<...>>` hence the error. Give it a `Comparator<Character>` instead:

```
Comparator<Character> order = Comparator.comparingInt(dict::get).reversed();
PriorityQueue<Character> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(order);
```

You can use an anonymous class instead of the `Comparator` static methods, though I really can't see any reason why you would.

Comment: Your code is ordering to ascending order. But I need it to descending order. And If I want to write the code compare method what should I do?

Comment: Use the `reversed` method. I've changed my code to reflect. I'd be interested to know why you want to write the `compare` code rather than use the `Comparator` static methods?

Comment: @Numery within in the IDE of your choice, click on the lambda expression version and select “convert to anonymous class”.

Comment: This is not about my IDE. My work place does not allow us to use all the Oracle libraries. And project is too old. Using older version version of jdk. So we are not able to use any lambda or method reference.

Comment: @Numery If you need to use an older version of Java then it would have been helpful to include that in your question. Lamba functions aren't the only Java feature that are version dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate for you help. This is not about my IDE. My work place does not allow us to use all the Oracle libraries. And project is too old. Using older version version of jdk. So we are not able to use any lambda or method reference. But I am able to figure out the solution.

1. Without Lambda --

   ```
   PriorityQueue<Character> maxHeap= new PriorityQueue(new Comparator<Character>(){           
        public int compare(Character c1, Character c2){
            return dicT.get(c2) - dicT.get(c1);
        }            
    });
   ```
2. With Lambda --

   ```
   PriorityQueue<Character> maxHeap =new PriorityQueue((x,y)->dicT.get(y)-dicT.get(x));
   ```
3. With Method Reference--

   ```
   PriorityQueue<Character> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue(Comparator.comparingInt(dicT::get).reversed());
   ```